# Apache proxy redirects from HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, artifactory

Below is apache reverse proxy configuration snippet which uses "ProxyPass" and "ProxyPassReverse"

```
Listen 1.2.3.4:80
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  SSLProxyEngine On
  ProxyPass /artifactory https://xxxx.xxxx.xxx/artifactory 
  ProxyPassReverse /artifactory https://xxxx.xxxx.xxx/artifactory
```

```
Listen 1.2.3.4:443
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:443>
  SSLProxyEngine On
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass /artifactory https://xxxx.xxxx.xxx/artifactory
  ProxyPassReverse /artifactory https://xxxx.xxxx.xxx/artifactory
</VirtualHost>
```

when I run below wget command, somehow it redirects to http:

```
#wget --no-check-certificate "https://xxxx.xxxx.xxx/artifactory/"
--2017-09-27 06:25:50--  
https://xxxx.xxxx.xxx/artifactory/
Resolving xxxx.xxxx.xxx... 1.2.3.4
Connecting to xxxx.xxxx.xxx|1.2.3.4|:443... connected.
WARNING: certificate common name “xxxx.xxxx.xxx” doesn't match requested 
host name “xxxx.xxxx.xxx”.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: http://xxxx.xxxx.xxx/artifactory/webapp/ [following]
--2017-09-27 06:25:51--  
http://xxxx.xxxx.xxx/artifactory/webapp/
Connecting to xxxx.xxxx.xxx|1.2.3.4|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1449 (1.4K) [text/html]
Saving to: “index.html.18”
```

If I run wget command with "/artifactory/webapp/#/home" it work on https:

```
wget --no-check-certificate "https://xxxx.xxxx.xxx/artifactory/webapp/#/home"
--2017-09-27 06:12:48-
https://xxxx.xxxx.xxx/artifactory/webapp/
Resolving xxxx.xxxx.xxx... 1.2.3.4
Connecting to xxxx.xxxx.xxx|1.2.3.4|:443... connected.
WARNING: certificate common name “xxxx.xxxx.xxx” doesn't 
match requested host name “xxxx.xxxx.xxx”.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1449 (1.4K) [text/html]
Saving to: “index.html.17”

2017-09-27 06:12:49 (73.1 MB/s) - “index.html.17” saved [1449/1449]
```

I have not defined redirects anywhere in proxy config file.

Could anyone suggest what could be the reason behind this behavior.? and how can I avoid getting it redirected to HTTP.?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have configured your reverse proxy to listen to the url ending with '/artifactory'. 
Consider adding the following:

```
RewriteRule ^/$                     /artifactory/webapp/ [R,L]
RewriteRule ^/artifactory(/)?$      /artifactory/webapp/ [R,L]
RewriteRule ^/artifactory/webapp$   /artifactory/webapp/ [R,L]
```

Also, are you using Artifactory OSS or Pro? If Pro than you have the option to generate the Apache configurations snippet directly from Artifactory.

Comment: Thanks Ariel. Does this rewrite rules needs to be added to both the sections ( 80 and 443)..? And since this apache used by other services as well, will first rewrite line impact other services which are defined in 80/443 sections.? I have enterprise edition of Artifactory. I can not use snippet generated proxy config due to too many services dependent on this apache proxy and I dont want to break/impact other services by adding config generated by snippet. Proxies running apache 2.2 is the another reason for not adding snippet config as it is.  2.2 might not support some parameters.